# How to get count of icons in tray using pywinauto

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto

I have an app which sits in tray when I click on .exe file. 
I am unable click on my app which sit in system tray. Because it doesn't have class_name or id or anything when I inspect using inspector.exe. So I decided to click this using index of icon. As I am not sure how many icons sit in tray when I run this particular program. So I wanted to get the count of the icon before I click the .exe file. If the count is x then I can click index x icon after clicking the .exe which actually clicks on my desired icon. 
Can any one help me in getting the count of the icons. I tried multiple times using child_window(class_name="") but it returned just an object instead of list.

Below is my code:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
import time

app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="explorer.exe")
st = app.window(class_name="Shell_TrayWnd")
t = st.child_window(title="Notification Chevron").wrapper_object()
t.click()

time.sleep(1)

list_box = Application(backend="uia").connect(class_name="NotifyIconOverflowWindow")
list_box_win = list_box.window(class_name="NotifyIconOverflowWindow")
list_box_win.wait('visible', timeout=30, retry_interval=3)
list_box_win.child_window(class_name="", found_index=x).click_input()
```

Your help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not giving the count and do the required job.
The following code will loop through the apps available in the system tray and clicks on the desired app by checking its name.

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
import time

app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="explorer.exe")
taskBar = app.window(class_name='Shell_TrayWnd')
trayIcon = taskBar["Notification Chevron"].wrapper_object()
trayIcon.click()

time.sleep(0.25)

trayWindowContainer = Application(backend="uia").connect(class_name="NotifyIconOverflowWindow")
trayWindow = trayWindowContainer.window(class_name="NotifyIconOverflowWindow")
trayWindow.wait('visible', timeout=30, retry_interval=3)

breakLoop: bool = False
for notification_area in trayWindow.children():
    for app_in_tray in notification_area.children():
        if "<App_name>" in str(app_in_tray):
            app_in_tray.click_input()
            breakLoop = True
            break
            if breakLoop:
                break
```